Solana CLI Transaction Timeout Error
I have been trying to learn the ins and out of the Solana CLI interface to better understand the chain but I keep running into a wall when I attempt to send SOL using CLI. I created my keypair and pubkey following Solana Cookbooks instructions but it errors out. Transaction attempts to finalize then gives me the error code of "Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds" However im using the Mainnet Beta and after checking my keypair balance I have more than enough SOL to complete the transaction. Code: solana transfer --from /home/chasebry13/.config/solana/id.json 5cAXKjr1n159QqREaq5VGHvWnN2ZufBFvK486wEzfibL 0.001 --allow-unfunded-recipient --fee-payer  /home/chasebry13/.config/solana/id.json

Does this answer your question? Getting Transaction Expiration Error on Mainnet

Clarifications added on April 7th, 2024, after the problem continues to persists:
I believe this new delay is a little war between BTC and Sol, due to the difference in overall fees.  Sol being much more advantageous that BTC now, they try to make Sol look bad with these fake delays that are indeed reals.  Without having evidence (sol status is 100%, so all should be fast: https://status.solana.com), I think some BTC users are clogging the Sol network with fake transfers that have a little 0.000001 SOL extra fees, so that all other transactions are put in the queue.
strong textRevised answer: April 5th, 2024:
I succeeded in transferring sol.  Here is the modified instruction that I used:
solana transfer CKDvoZNyNP????-???dfAt8vfZs 0.1 --allow-unfunded-recipient --with-compute-unit-price 0.00????? --config C:\Users????.config\solana\cli\config.yml
Replace de ? to fit your own context.
I hope it will help you, as it should work this way.  Maybe it will work with the regular instruction also.  I do not know.  Maybe there is a little congestion due to the fact that many persons are using the priority fees at the same time, so if one does not use the priority fees (normal transfer), then the transaction failed due to "too long to confirm".
============  My original answer of April 4th, 2024,  that should work for other cases where there is a mess in the configuration files of remote PC ======
I had the same problem, if you look at my question (just before yours in the time line of questions).  I described in greater details than you.  You might want to look at my question?
Now that I saw your question, I think that the problem might be related to a problem with Solana cluster or anything we do not have access.
For my part, if I have a problem similar to this problem, I did what I explained in my question:
1- I uninstall the existing "remote PC set up, as I suspect it might have errors in it".
2-  I reinstall a new "remote PC set up" provided by Solana, or if you prefer, the Solana install tool.
3- I tried again to do the transaction (but it failed again, so now, I suspect that the problem comes from Solana, somewhere or that there is a hidden nonce transaction on my account).
I just do not know for now and since i already did everything that seems "logical to me", then I will stop and wait and see if Solana will fix this problem.  I mean, I have been doing this transaction for years and it always work... so?  probably it is not coming from my side (or your side).
